# Detect if property is animatable by CSS3 transition?

Tags: javascript, animation, css, transform, transition

The list of properties that can be animated with a CSS3 transition is not consistent among browsers and is a subject to change with new browser versions. For example, -moz-transform is not animatable with -moz-transition in FF3.6 but it is in FF4.

So, is there a way to detect in JavaScript if a particular property is animatable? I wouldn't like to use user agent sniffing as it's not reliable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mourner It would be rad if you could unaccept my answer and accept Jordan's, just for people googling this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: see [Jordan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11217022/524555) for a good technique on detecting animatable properties.**

I'm afraid there is no straightforward way to detect if a property is animatable. However, the properties are consistent for the most part (the only problem I've encountered is with FF4 transition + text shadow + transform).

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#the-transition-property-property-#properties-from-css-

Firefox 3.6 doesn't support css transitions, you can detect this with a js library such as Modernizr:

http://www.modernizr.com/

Comment: Thanks! I was sure there was some stable version of FF where there was transition support without animatable transform, but it turns out that this was in some of FF4 betas and now everything seems to be OK.

Comment: I've been thinking about this for another project, and it is actually possible—see below. :)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is a way. Demonstration follows, explanation below. There are some **very important caveats** involved, so make sure you read on.

The following code will test if the browser can animate between two values.

## The code

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/8L9CM/9/).

```js
/*
@param property  The property to test.
@param from      A valid starting value for the animation.
@param to        A valid ending value for the animation.
@param [element] The element to test with. (Required for testing
                 properties with prerequisites, e.g. "top" requires
                 non-static position.)
*/
function isAnimationSupported(property, from, to, element) {
    var doc = document.documentElement,
        style = doc.appendChild(document.createElement("style")),
        rule = [
                'capTest{',
                    '0%{',   property, ':', from, '}',
                    '100%{', property, ':', to,   '}',
                '}'
               ].join(''),
        propCamel = property.toCamelCase(),
        prefixes = 'moz ms o webkit '.split(' '), // Unprefixed last, see comments.
        prefixCount = prefixes.length,
        canAnimate = false;

    element = doc.appendChild((element)
            ? element.cloneNode(false)
            : document.createElement('div'));

    // Detect invalid start value. (Webkit tries to use default.)
    element.style[propCamel] = to;

    // Iterate through supported prefixes.
    for (var i = 0; i < prefixCount; i++) {

        // Variations on current prefix.
        var prefix  = prefixes[i],
            hPrefix = (prefix) ? '-' + prefix + '-' : '',
            uPrefix = (prefix) ? prefix.toUpperCase() + '_' : '';

        // Test for support.
        if (CSSRule[uPrefix + 'KEYFRAMES_RULE']) {

            // Rule supported; add keyframe rule to test stylesheet.
            style.sheet.insertRule('@'+ hPrefix + 'keyframes ' + rule, 0);

            // Apply animation.
            var animationProp = (hPrefix + 'animation').toCamelCase();
            element.style[animationProp] = 'capTest 1s 0s both';

            // Get initial computed style.
            var before = getComputedStyle(element)[propCamel];

            // Skip to last frame of animation.
            // BUG: Firefox doesn't support reverse or update node style while
            // attached.
            doc.removeChild(element);
            element.style[animationProp] = 'capTest 1s -1s alternate both';
            doc.appendChild(element);
            // BUG: Webkit doesn't update style when animation skipped ahead.
            element.style[animationProp] = 'capTest 1s 0 reverse both';

            // Get final computed style.
            var after = getComputedStyle(element)[propCamel];

            // If before and after are different, property and values are animable.
            canAnimate = before !== after;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Clean up the test elements.
    doc.removeChild(element);
    doc.removeChild(style);

    return canAnimate;
}

// Cribbed from Lea Verou's prefixfree.
String.prototype.toCamelCase = function() {
    return this.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function($0, $1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); })
               .replace('-','');
};
```

## How to use

The mandatory arguments for this are the property to animate and the starting and finishing values it should take. Optionally, you can pass an element with other initial styles set, e.g. `position: absolute`. (The function clones the element, so you can pass nodes from the document and they won't be changed.) If you don't pass any element, the animation is tested on a `div` with whatever default styles the UA applies.

## How it works

A keyframe animation rule is added to a dummy stylesheet, with the initial frame set to the `from` value and the final frame set to the `to` value. This animation is applied to an element. We then inspect the computed style for the animated property to see if it is different when the animation starts from the initial frame compared to when it starts from the final frame.

The reason this works is because the animable properties for both transitions and keyframe animations are the same, and the browser will only apply keyframe values if the property supports animation.

## Caveats (read before using, some of these are nasty!)

There are several inconsistencies in how browsers handle animations. A couple of these I have worked around in as future-proof a way as possible; however, a few of them are intractable.

Most notably, Firefox tweens position values (e.g. `left`) on static elements while others (e.g. Webkit and Opera) do not. It doesn't actually *move* the element, but the value of that property is updated. Thus, you will get different results between browsers if you try to animate a position value without passing a non-statically positioned element.

The most current versions of major browsers that support CSS transitions also support CSS keyframes, although some older versions support the former but not the latter. (E.g. Opera 11.)

Finally, if I were doing this more elegantly I would use [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) to determine the correct prefix to use directly; currently I test against an array of prefixes, starting with the unprefixed version.

Comment: +1 Very cool! It gives false on `top right left bottom` because the test div is not absolutely positioned. I'm not sure how to handle this, perhaps you can pass an element to override the test div?

Comment: Good point! Adding an optional element parameter seems like a good idea; I actually got as far as updating the fiddle when my broadband went dead. I'll update the explanation when I get back online! :)

Comment: Cool! Another good test would be animating css transforms on inline elements, that's supposed to fail.

Comment: @Duopixel Oh man. I've made some significant changes to how it works, but take special note of the caveats. __tl;dr__: Firefox tweens position properties on static elements. Note also that *both* browsers tween the transform matrix for inline elements, so it returns a positive for animating transforms on both inline and block elements. On the plus side, the updated version will tell you if you can tween between both properties, so returns false in e.g. Webkit when animating from a pixel value to a percentage value.

Comment: That's so weird. The transformation is not applied to the computed style in web inspector with inline elements. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Duopixel That it is. The computed style value definitely changes; Webkit-only demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/kpPNx/ (My guess is that it's applied in case display is updated later.)

Comment: You're right, I think this is as good as it gets. I've updated my answer to point to yours.

Comment: Chrome gives error Failed to parse the rule '@keyframes capTest{0%{height:1px}100%{height:100px}}'. I think prefixed versions should be first and then unprefixed this way: prefixes = 'moz ms o webkit '.split(' '),.

Comment: Hey @Timo—sorry for the lack of response! I've checked it out and you're right about the Chrome error; I'll update my answer; might come back to it later, though, because I was testing in Chrome previously and it wasn't raising an exception then!

Comment: @Timo And, naturally: thank you! Really appreciate you spotting this and suggesting a fix. :)

Comment: It may be due Chrome dropped prefix in some recent version. The answer is from 2012 and then prefix was needed.

Comment: @Timo Ah, of course—I was being a dunderhead. That's actually what I intended (for the unprefixed version to be used where possible), but for some reason my mental logic was backwards and I put it first by mistake.